# How can I get the results from multiple pages in an API response?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to paginate through all the results for a specific of a ChartMogul Customers.All() API call. I'm using the [Chartmogul NPM package](https://github.com/chartmogul/chartmogul-node).

It works, I can get all the results, but I have more results than the max number of records allowed in a single call, so I need to page through multiple pages of results. And I'm stuck how to elegantly do it.

I could do multiple calls first grabbing the total amount of pages, followed by a loop that goes through all pages. Saving all results in one big object.

This is the call, with the `page` variable should get updated to x page.

```js
ChartMogul.Customer.all(config, {
    status: 'Active',
    per_page: 200,
    page: page
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) reject(err);
    console.log(res);
    resolve(res.entries);
});
```

Each API response from chartmogul contains the following details

```
{
  "entries":[
    {
      "id": 25647,
      "uuid": "cus_de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546012",
      "external_id": "34916129",
      "external_ids": ["34916129"],
      "data_source_uuid": "ds_610b7a84-c50f-11e6-8aab-97d6db98913a",
      "data_source_uuids": ["ds_610b7a84-c50f-11e6-8aab-97d6db98913a"],
      "name": "Example Company",
      "company": "",
      "email": "bob@examplecompany.com",
      "status": "Active",
      "lead_created_at": "2015-01-01T10:00:00-04:00",
      "free_trial_started_at": "2015-01-09T10:00:00-04:00",
      "customer-since": "2015-06-09T13:16:00-04:00",
      "city": "Nowhereville",
      "state": "Alaska",
      "country": "US",
      "zip": "0185128",
      "attributes":{
        "tags": ["engage", "unit loss", "discountable"],
        "stripe":{
          "uid": 7,
          "coupon": true
        },
        "clearbit":{
          "company":{
            "name": "Example Company",
            "legalName": "Example Company Inc.",
            "domain": "examplecompany.com",
            "url": "http://examplecompany.com",
            "category":{
              "sector": "Information Technology",
              "industryGroup": "Software and Services",
              "industry": "Software",
              "subIndustry": "Application Software"
            },
            "metrics":{
              "raised": 1502450000,
              "employees": 1000,
              "googleRank": 7,
              "alexaGlobalRank": 2319,
              "marketCap": null
            },
          },
          "person":{
            "name":{
              "fullName": "Bob Kramer"
            },
            "employment":{
              "name": "Example Company"
            }
          }
        },
        "custom":{
          "CAC": 213,
          "utmCampaign": "social media 1",
          "convertedAt": "2015-09-08 00:00:00",
          "pro": false,
          "salesRep": "Gabi"
        }
      },
      "address":{
        "address_zip": "0185128",
        "city": "Nowhereville",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "Alaska"
      },
      "mrr": 3000,
      "arr": 36000,
      "billing-system-url": "https:\/\/dashboard.stripe.com\/customers\/cus_4Z2ZpyJFuQ0XMb",
      "chartmogul-url": "https:\/\/app.chartmogul.com\/#customers\/25647-Example_Company",
      "billing-system-type": "Stripe",
      "currency": "USD",
      "currency-sign": "$"
    },
    {"...49 more...": "...entries..."}
  ],
  "has_more": true,
  "per_page": 50,
  "page": 1,
  "current_page": 1,
  "total_pages": 4
}
```

So how can I loop through all pages of a response in a simple, elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern should get you well on your way.

Use a  function that returns the main promise and when there are more you return a recursive call to that function (another promise) or you return the combined results.

Following is untested and having never used this API might need some tweaking.

```
function getEntries(config, page=0, entries = []) {
  // return promise
  return ChartMogul.Customer.all(config, {
    status: 'Active',
    per_page: 200,
    page: page
  }).then(res => {
    // merge into main array
    entries = [...entries, ...res.entries];
    // return another promise if there are more ... or return the combined array
    return res.has_more ? getEntries(config, res.page+1, entries) : entries;
  });

}

getEntries(config)
    .then(entries => console.log(entries) )
    .catch(err => console.error(err) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Like charlietfl I recommend you use promises. The difference is I would start all the requests at the same time and then wait for all of them to finish.

Depending on the number of pages you need to get this method is faster, but it might send too many requests if you need more than [40 requests/second](https://dev.chartmogul.com/docs/rate-limits)

This can only be done if you know how many pages there are beforehand.

(This has not been tested since i don't have a api key)

```js
// start a promise for every page given
function startRequests(pages) {
    return pages.map((page) => ChartMogul.Customer.all(config, {
        status: 'Active',
        per_page: 200,
        page: page
    }))
}

// an array of all the pages you want to get from the server.
// the function below could be used to generate the page numbers
// Array.from({length: numberOfPages}, (x,i) => i + 1);
let pages = [1,2,3,4] 

let requestPromises = startRequests(pages)

// wait for the promises to finish
Promise.all(requestPromises)
.then(function(results) {
    // combine all the results into a single array
    return results.reduce((combinedResults, result) => [...combinedResults, result.entries], [])
}).then((combinedResults) => {
    // do whatever is needed
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: # of pages is likely unknown until at least the first request is made

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, but he mentioned that he could get the pages with another request. Assuming that is an option, I think my method would be faster if it is expected to get 20 pages. But seeing your answer I would probably choose it since it is more reliable.

Comment: If OP has some reason for wanting to get the results in pages, then it's possible that this answer would put too much strain on memory or bandwidth (if the actual number of results is much larger than in this example). Although in that case charlietfl's answer may also not be good enough, since it outputs all the results as a single array. However, without more details about what OP is trying to do we can't do much about that.